# how to do model prediction using python in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, keras, prediction

This is the python code, and it works so well in **Python**:

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import json
import numpy as np

filepath = 'model2.h5'
test_img = 'falling14145853.png'
model = keras.models.load_model(filepath)

img = image.load_img(test_img, target_size=(150, 150))

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size = 10)

_mapping = ["falling", "sitting", "standing"]
a = np.concatenate(classes, axis=None).astype(int).tolist()
idx = np.argmax(a[0])
prediction = _mapping[idx]
response_json = {"Prediction" : prediction}
data_in_json = json.dumps(response_json)
with open("prediction.json", "w") as out:
    out.write(data_in_json)
```

And this is in **Matlab**:

```
system('test_model.py'); %doing prediction
```

This is the Matlab output and I have tried to run python to make a capture using CV and works so well in Matlab, but when I tried to run python code which contains of keras, its showing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\angie\test_model.py", line 1, in 
> import keras
> ImportError: No module named keras

Comment: Matlab supports Python 2.7, 3.7 and 3.8. Is your Python code in a different version than that? It's possible you're using one interpreter that has keras and one that does not (in Matlab).

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 and I've been checked in matlab using pyenv it shows the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding 'python.
So the code becomes

```
system('python test_model.py');
```

and just it.